# My postgresql database not showing many to many field column but django admin page does. Why?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I hope you got the question from the title itself.

After migrating I can select multiple fields from that many to many field in django admin page but when I click on save it saves in the admin page of django but when I check the postgresql database everything that is not many to many field saves but the table lacks many to many field column.

Comment: You can ask question when you got the error with some problem stuff(code) or (error) it's help the community user to understood better the you problem

Answer (score 4):

There are no many-to-many connections in Postgres, nor other SQL databases as far as I know.  These connections are generally made thru a third table (called thru-table sometimes), connecting values from two tables.
Django does this behind the scenes for you.
You should find the third table in the database.  There are default names for them and you can choose a name too.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the database in graphical interfaces such as pgadmin or in the terminal, you will see that none of the databases show the many-to-many relationship, but in practice everything is in order and working.
This could be because you can't change it through tools like pgadmin, and the reason of many-to-many relationships are null = True by default is probably because you can't change them in user interfaces.